# Custom UITableViewCell Leading Alignment to Right Detail Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am using a `UITableView` with static `UITableViewCells`. I am using custom cells and also right detail cells. I would like to get the `UILabel` within the custom cells to align with the `UILabel` within the right detail cells.

I checked within Interface Builder, and it shows the `UILabel` in the right detail cell to have the x origin to be 15. Within the custom `UITableViewCell`, I set the `UILabel` to have the same starting x origin. This works great on iPhones, but when I load the app on an iPad, they aren't aligned properly. The UILabel within the right detail cells appear to have a starting x origin of about 18.

Is there something I can do to ensure the UILabels have the same leading alignment within Interface Builder, or do I need to programmatically set constraints depending on the type of device?

Comment: Do you use auto-layout?

Comment: Yes I am using auto layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there's an easy way to make constraints based on Apple's pre-made cells. You'll probably have to go with just programming the constraints manually, or another option is to make your own implementation of a right detail cell and make the constraints the same as your other custom cell.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I just ended up adding constraints programmatically.